# Angular hide first element in array in a ng-repeat without emptying array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to do something like this

```
<md-card class="saved-search animated" ng-repeat="search in vm.savedSearches" md-theme="default" md-theme-watch>
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
            <span class="md-title md-body-2">{{search.address[0]}}</span>
            <span class="md-subhead">{{search.address | remainingAddress}}</span>
        </md-card-header-text>

function remainingAddress() {
    return remainingAddress;

    ////////////////

    function remainingAddress(input) {
        let newArray = input;
        return input ? newArray.shift().join(',') : input;
    }
}
```

What I want to show first line of address as header which works, and the remaining part of the address on the next line. But the problem is with the remaining address and shift() it always returns empty array I guess because the multiple shift() clears out the array in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `limitTo` filter alongside with the `Array.join` method:

```
<span class="md-title md-body-2">{{search.address[0]}}</span>
<span class="md-subhead">
    {{ (search.address | limitTo: -(search.address.length - 1)).join(',') }}
</span>
```

By passing a negative number `-n` to `limitTo` filter you're asking it to return the last `n` items of the array.

Reference: [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

Comment: yup that's it, didn't know about the negative trick. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

shift doesnt return array, it returns removed array element, try this

```
function remainingAddress() {
    return remainingAddress;

    ////////////////

    function remainingAddress(input) {
        let newArray = input;
        if(input){
            newArray.shift()
            return newArray.join(',')
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I tried something like that as well it still clears the original array completely, I don't really understand it.

Comment: I think its because it's in a loop, it just clears out the array completely.